# Opening a strait binary file with iOS

Tags: ios, file-io, binaryfiles

I wrote a custom file type that data from my Java program gets saved to. I want to get the data out on an iPod/Pad/Phone. So far I wrote this file for reading strait byte values from a file and changing them into NSStrings and integers.

```
#import "BinaryFileReader.h"

@implementation BinaryFileReader

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithLocation:(NSString*)filepath {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filepath];
        _fileOffset = 0;
        if (_file == nil)
            NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open file at path:",filepath);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)close {
    [_file closeFile];
}

- (int)readInt {
    [_file seekToFileOffset:_fileOffset];
    _databuffer = [_file readDataOfLength:4];
    _fileOffset+=4;
    return (int)[_databuffer bytes];
}

- (NSString*)readNSString {
    int length = [self readInt];
    [_file seekToFileOffset:_fileOffset];
    _databuffer = [_file readDataOfLength:length];
    _fileOffset+=length;
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_databuffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSMutableArray*)readNSMutableArrayOfNSString {
    NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int arrayLength = [self readInt];
    int length;
    for (int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
        length = [self readInt];
        [_file seekToFileOffset:_fileOffset];
        _databuffer = [_file readDataOfLength:length];
        _fileOffset+=length;
        [array addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_databuffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    return array;
}

@end
```

Now when I try to use this to read NSStrings or integers it does not come up with the right values. I assume since both NSStrings and integers are coming up wrong it's something in the  readInt method. Anyone see something glaringly obvious that I've missed here?

Edit:

The file format that I am trying to read starts with a string. That string, when read with readNSString, is the correct string but the first 1/3 of the string is missing.

Java code:

```
public void saveItem() {
    try {
        byte[] bytes;
        FileOutputStream output;
        if (countOccurrences(location.getPath(),'.')==1) {
            System.out.println("Option 1");
            output = new FileOutputStream(location+"/"+name+".dtb");
        } else {
            output = new FileOutputStream(location);
        }

        bytes = name.getBytes("UTF-8");
        output.write(bytes.length);
        output.write(bytes);

        output.write(otherNames.length);
        for (int i=0;i<otherNames.length;i++) {
            bytes = otherNames[i].getBytes("UTF-8");
            output.write(bytes.length);
            output.write(bytes);
        }

        bytes = description.getBytes("UTF-8");
        output.write(bytes.length);
        output.write(bytes);

        bytes = XactCode.getBytes("UTF-8");
        output.write(bytes.length);
        output.write(bytes);

        bytes = SymbilityCode.getBytes("UTF-8");
        output.write(bytes.length);
        output.write(bytes);

        output.write(averageLowPrice);

        output.write(averageHighPrice);

        output.write(averageLifeExpectancy);

        output.close();
        bytes = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Endian issues come to mind.  If your Java program is running on Windows then all of the bytes will be reverse from what you want.

Comment: Well I can tell you both the Java program used to create it and the xcode environment used to code this are on a Mac. Also I know that it isn't a Big Endian/Little Endian issue as when I read a NSString, it reads about 2/3 of the CORRECT string from the file, just not all of the string.

Comment: Alright, that at least is good to know, but I suggest you edit your question to reflect this so others don't spend time thinking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this does not work is the way you are casting the `NSData` to `int`.  The `bytes` methods returns a **pointer** to the actual data, which you will need to deference to get the actual value (otherwise you will just be getting the memory address of the pointer).

I tried two ways:

```
int test = 64;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&test length:4];
int test2 = (int)[data bytes]; //This gave me 170382992
```

and

```
int test = 64;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&test length:4];
int test2 = *((int *)[data bytes]); //This gave me 64
```

Comment: So my code should be {
    return *((int *)[_databuffer bytes]);
} then?

Comment: If I do this ^ I get a nil "address=0x0" problem.

Comment: NSData will return `nil` from `bytes` if it has no data.  You need to check.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the readInt method above with stated changes returns the integer "1936019979" however that is not the value stored there. So this fix didn't make fix it. (p.s., I know the value in there is stored correctly because I can still use the file correctly in the java program.

Comment: What is the result of NSLogging the data buffer?

Comment: This is the NSLog output <0b526573>

Comment: Then the integer is correct.  0x7365520b == 1936019979 Something is wrong with the way you are reading the data from the file.

Comment: Well everything I am doing to read from the file is in question/code except that I am calling readNSString once. I know I am reading the data out of the file wrong and I know it is the INT I'm reading out of the file wrong. My question even states all this. I understand there IS a problem. I just don't know what it is.

Comment: I mean that the format you *think* the data is in is different from what it actually is.  If you are getting those bytes, then you are probably in the wrong position in the file (Is there some header info, or other data?  We don't know what the Java did)

Comment: Share that code too!!!  Or if you don't have it explain why you are assuming that it is in this format.

Comment: Try it with just a simple test case (i.e. 4 Test) and analyze the output file with a hex editor to verify that the output is what you expect and that FileOutputStream has not inserted a BOM or anything like that.  I don't think it will insert a BOM but the correct file should be 04 00 00 00 54 65 73 74